# when I try to use find inside loopback model js file.iam getting error as Error: Cannot call user.find(). The find method has not been setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop

Error: Cannot call user.find(). The find method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource!
user.js is inside server/models/user.js

```
module.exports = function(User) {
    User.find({where: {id:'3'}}, function(err,data) { 
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
      });
};
```

Comment: Could you provide with your mode-config.json and datasources.json?

Comment: model-config.json

{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ]
  },
  "user": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  }
}

Comment: datasources.json

{
  "db": {
    "host": "15.0.0.18",
    "port": 0,
    "url": "10.0.0.1",
    "database": "loopback_sample",
    "password": "***",
    "name": "local",
    "connector": "mysql",
    "user": "sample"
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

Your current model-config.json file has this line:

```
"user": { "dataSource": "db" }
```

Make the U capital in user as this is creating a new model user with lowercase letter and i think you haven't created its model files like user.js and user.json. It looks like you want to extend the built-in User model, in that case you can use this lowercase user model but keep both the model definitions in the model-config.js and use User as base in user.json file. Check [Docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Extending+built-in+models) there is clear explanation for this

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with the "user" having a lowercase "u". Following the StrongLoop documentation, it looks like you've generated a model but not linked it to a data source.

In the documentation, it advises you to create a model and then change the datasource afterward. When you generate your model, the storage that is available for you to set will only be "db", which is an in-memory provider.

To get your API path to work correctly, firstly generate your model using:

```
slc loopback:model
```

Once you have generated your model, then run:

```
slc loopback:datasource
```

Which will then prompt you to fill in some options about your data source. Here's an example using MongoDB (note, where there is no data after the ':' is where you press enter to use the default value):

```
? Enter the data-source name: name_i_want_to_use_for_this
? Select the connector for name_i_want_to_use_for_this: MongoDB (supported by StrongLoop)
Connector-specific configuration:
? Connection String url to override other settings (eg: mongodb://username:password@hostname:port/database): 
? host: localhost
? port: 
? user: 
? password: 
? database: mydbname
? Install loopback-connector-mongodb@^1.4 Yes
```

This will then provide you with a connection provider called `name_i_want_to_use_for_this`. Now go into your `/server/model-config.json` and then scroll down to the name of your model and you will see:

```
  "name_of_my_model": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  }
```

Change this to:

```
  "name_of_my_model": {
    "dataSource": "name_i_want_to_use_for_this",
    "public": true
  }
```

Now you're done, go back into your strongloop project directory and run `node .`, and browse to `http://localhost:3000/explorer`. Go to the method you wanted to test, and test it in the explorer again, and it should now insert the data into the model.

To test this has worked, create a new record using the explorer, and then query its ID using the explorer.